# OSVR IR tracker

Tags: json, tracking, virtual-reality, infrared, osvr

I am currently using the OSVR HMD and I'm trying to figure out how to use the IR tracker that comes with the VR headset. In [this](https://github.com/OSVR/OSVR-Core/blob/master/plugins/videobasedtracker/doc/Running.md) article, it is suggested to use the `osvr_server_config.VideoBasedHMDTracker.sample.json` configuration file but it seems that it as been removed from the osvr core snapshot.

What is the current configuration file to enable the IR tracker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply, but:
With the latest core (at least), all that's needed is to launch osvr_server.exe.

I had some connection problems with mine and actually had to cut away some plastic around the usb-port.